# Multi Label Image Classifier Input Issues

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

Hello I am trying to build a multi label image classifier but I am having issues with the input shape.

My features.shape is (40000, 28, 28, 1). The image is of two letters ranging from (a-g) in the photo that are to be classified. The third dimension (1) I manually added to it because from my understanding the Conv2D needs a 3 dimensional shape.

labels.shape is (40000, 2) and it is an array with the two letters associated with each photo.

Here is my model:

```
    model = keras.Sequential([
    Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    Dense(7, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

When I train the model I receive the error
`` ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 7) vs (None, 2)). ``

I am assuming I need to reshape the labels or features somehow but I am not sure.

I have been trying multiple different inputs and changes to no avail. I appreciate any help on this problem.

Comment: From my understanding on multi-label image classification the model needs to have the same number of dense neurons as the number of letters I am trying to predict.

Comment: I don't think this is multi-label classification, you basically have two independent multi-class classification problems (7 classes x 2).

Comment: No I do not believe it is a multi-class classification. From my understanding multi-class classification is where the sample can only be labeled as one class. I need my model to identify two classes in each image not just one. If letters a and b are in the image I need it to predict that a and b are present in the image. That is why I believe it is multi-label classification

Comment: No, that is incorrect, you want two independent sets of classes to be predicted, multi-label can predict from 0 to 7 classes in this case, again, what I said is you have two independent multi-class classification problems, which can be implemented with two output heads. For example a multi-label classifier would not be able to predict the same class two times. If you insist to use multi-label, try to do binary encoding of your labels and see what happens.

Comment: You were correct and I was mistaken. Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it correctly; the problem is with the last Dense layer since you are doing two label output change the last layer to `Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')` instead of `Dense(7, activation='sigmoid')`

Comment: Does that still allow for the model to recognize all of the letters from a to g or only two letters? From my understanding on multi-label image classification the model needs to have the same number of dense neurons as the number of letters I am trying to predict.

Comment: Yes it should work